# How to create a compound field in group by in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that contains 2 fields (for simplicity). the first one is the one that I want to group by on, and the second one is the one that I want to show as a comma separated text field. How to do it?

So my data is like this:

```
col 1           col2
------          ------
Ashkan           s1
Ashkan           s2
Ashkan           s3
Hasan            k1
Hasan            k2 
Hasan            k3
Hasan            kachal
```

I want this

```
col1     count      combination
------   ------     -------
Ashkan     3         s1, s2,s3
Hasan      4         k1, k2,k3,kachal
```

I can do the group by like below, but how to do the combination?

```
 select [col1],count(*)  
  FROM mytable
  group by [col1]
  order by count(*)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `FOR XML PATH` for this:

```
select col1, count(*) ,
       STUFF((SELECT ',' + col2 
              FROM mytable AS t2
              WHERE t2.col1 = t1.col1
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') 
FROM mytable AS t1
group by col1
order by count(*)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `FOR XML PATH('')` to concatenate the strings:

```
WITH Tbl(col1, col2) AS(
    SELECT * FROM(VALUES
        ('Ashkan',  's1'),
        ('Ashkan',  's2'),
        ('Ashkan',  's3'),
        ('Hasan',   'k1'),
        ('Hasan',   'k2'),
        ('Hasan',   'k3'),
        ('Hasan',   'kachal')
    ) t(a,b)
)
SELECT 
    col1,
    [count] = COUNT(*),
    x.combination
FROM Tbl t
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT STUFF((
        SELECT ', ' + col2
        FROM Tbl
        WHERE col1 = t.col1
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 2, '')  AS combination
) x
GROUP BY t.col1, x.combination;
```